# Entity Framework and Stored Procedure Function Import with nullable parameters

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity

I noticed that when Entity Framework generates a method for a stored procedure (function import), it tests to see if the parameter is null, and makes a decision like this:

```
if (contactID.HasValue)
{
  contactIDParameter = new ObjectParameter("contactID", contactID);
}  
else
{
  contactIDParameter = new ObjectParameter("contactID", typeof(global::System.Int32));
}
```

I don't understand what its trying to do by passing the Type of the parameter as a parameter when the parameter is null? Exactly how does the stored procedure/function get executed in this case?

I did a test myself with SQL Profiler, and noticed that when I intentionally pass null as a parameter (by calling something like context.MyProcedure(null) ), null is simply passed as the parameter to the SQL server's stored procedure.

Some clarifications on this behavior would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was interested in this question so I made some investigation.

`ObjectParameter` has two overloads - one for passing value and one for passing the type. The second is used if you pass null as the parameter value because EF internally need this. The reason is that function import must be called with ObjectParameters, not with plain parameters you are passing to the wrapping method.

Internally EF calls:

```
private EntityCommand CreateEntityCommandForFunctionImport(string functionName, out EdmFunction functionImport, params ObjectParameter[] parameters)
{
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
    {
        if (parameters[i] == null)
        {
            throw EntityUtil.InvalidOperation(Strings.ObjectContext_ExecuteFunctionCalledWithNullParameter(i));
        }
    }
    ...
    this.PopulateFunctionEntityCommandParameters(parameters, functionImport, command);
    return command;
}
```

As you can see even null value must be represented as ObjectParameter because you can't simply pass null - it will throw exception. The `PopulateFunctionEntityCommandParameters` uses information about the type to create correct `DbParameter` for calling the stored procedure. The value of that parameter is `DBNull.Value`.

So you don't have to deal with it. It is just infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

When you watch the code of the class `ObjectParameter` constructors

```
public ObjectParameter (string name, object value)
public ObjectParameter (string name, Type type)
```

You can see that `ObjectParameter` has 3 important private fields:

`_name` (name of parameter, not null and immutable), `_type` (CLR type of the parameter, not null and immutable), `_value` (value of the parameter, can be changed and nullable)

When the first constructor is used, these fields are all initialized. With the second constructor, the `_value` field is left to be `null`.

In the `ExecuteFunction` of EF, a private method `CreateEntityCommandForFunctionImport` is used which calls another even deeper private method `PopulateFunctionImportEntityCommandParameters` which attaches the entity parameters.

Inside `PopulateFunctionImportEntityCommandParameters`, an instance of `EntityParameter` which represents a parameter in `EntityCommand` will be mapped to the name and value's properties of `ObjectParameter`.

This instruction explains it all:

```
entityParameter.Value = objectParameter.Value ?? DBNull.Value;
```

We pass the `DBNull` to EF if no value was specified as a parameter.